# Change while to repeat ... until

Tags: algorithms, loops, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

If I have this script:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \While{$x = y$}
    \State Something
  \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
```

I want to change `while` with `repeat .. until`. I tried `\Repeat .. \Until` but it doesn't work. How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a snippet from the package documentation at
http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf (page 6).

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Repeat
    \Comment{forever}
    \State this\Until{you die.}
\end{algorithmic}
```

[image]

Comment: It's giving me an error telling `! Undefined control sequence.` at `\repeat`.

Comment: I was having the same issue and I realized the problem was that I wrote some statements without using \State prior to the loop.

Comment: @Nappa Notice the command is `\Repeat` not `\repeat`.